# aws elasticache redis on notify-keyspace-events event trigger not able catch

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using AWS ElastiCache and checking the event trigger on expiration. This one I'm checking on `redis-cli`, I've added a screenshot also.
[image]

Even I've added new new parameter group and set `notify-keyspace-events` key value to `KEA`
[image]

but still, all the `notify-keyspace-events`  are not able to catch. I'm I missing any another config in order catch these events?.

Comment: Did you add the new parameter group to your cluster?

Comment: May I know how can I check this ?

Comment: Right now I have only one node